# Dealing with fragmented UDP

Tags: network-programming, udp

Ok, before anyone asks, TCP is not an option.

So, I'm sending some messages over UDP. Each message has a 4 byte length field at the beginning. Thus far, I've been using this field to determine if I have a complete message.

But I wondered, if I have two large messages, large enough that they are both fragmented like this:

```
Message 1
Length 1 | Fragment 1-1 | Fragment 1-2 | Fragment 1-3

Message 2
Length 2 | Fragment 2-1 | Fragment 2-2 | Fragment 2-3
```

and I send one immediately after the other, is it possible for them to be delivered interleaved like this:

```
Length 1 | Length 2 | Fragment 1-1 | Fragment 2-1 | Fragment 1-2 | Fragment 2-2 | Fragment 1-3 | Fragment 2-3
```

And if so, how can I possibly reassemble these if I don't have any control of how the message is fragmented?

EDIT: Also.. It just occurred to me that UDP might not fragment, and the "fragmentation" I'm seeing might be from calling the `.receive()` method with a fixed size buffer. So maybe this is not even a problem. Can anyone confirm if UDP fragments?

Comment: There are two different types of fragmentation here:  fragmentation of UDP itself and secondly how to fragment large messages into multiple UDP packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't possible. UDP datagrams are delivered entire and intact or not at all. You don't have to worry about interleaving or reassembly. All you have to worry about is non-delivery, duplicate delivery, and out-of-order delivery ;-)

If you think you're seeing fragmentation, you're really seeing a programming bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions (I added an edit). I'm glad thats "all" i have to worry about.